# Jquery - Change content styles iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change styles css inside at a iframe, using:

```
$("#box_close").click(function(){
("#iframe").contents().find("#scrolling_box").removeClass("scrollingBox");
$("#iframe").contents().find("#scrolling_box").addClass("scrollingBoxCustom");
});
```

Not working ok because the attribute src is in different host that index file, so it gives a classic browser policy error when trying to access a resource that is not on the same host.

Is there some another way I can change styles from the html content of an iframe from a page hosted on another server?

Thanks,

Comment: No...there is no way to access it due to *"same origin policy"*. There are ways if you control the code on other domain though

Comment: No,third-party  i-frame  can not be change at your end (no css/html/jquery)

Comment: Just as an out of scope hint you may be interested in: A way would be to use PHP `file_get_contents()` to "proxie" or "scrape" the document...